# "Beer never tastes so good" or "Beer never tasted so good."

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between "Beer never tastes so good" and "Beer never tasted so good?"

Comment: More context, please.

Answer (score 1):

They can be interpreted differently.

> 1. Beer never tasted so good.

might be rephrased:

> Beer has never tasted this good! This beer is the best beer ever!

Next,

> 2. Beer never tastes so good.

might be rephrased.

> Beer never tastes very good. In other words, I don't like beer.